# What's the time complexity to find all substrings?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I made this code to generate all unique substrings given a string, and I'm struggling to find the complexity of the code when I use recursion. I think a good complexity of time for this problem is O(N²), but what is my complexity and how can I improve my code?

```
'''
          a            b          c    d 
       ab ac ad      bc bd      cd
     abc abd acd   bcd
   abcd

'''
dict_poss = {}

#get all letters
def func(string):
    for i,value in enumerate(string):           
        dict_poss[value] = True 
        recursive(value,string[i+1:])   

#get all combinations
def recursive(letter,string):   
    for i,value in enumerate(string):           
        if letter+value not in dict_poss:
            dict_poss[letter+value] = True;
        recursive(letter+value,string[i+1:])    
    return  

func("abcd")
print(dict_poss)
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you have written at the top there, you are trying to find all possible sub*sequences* of the string, in which case this will be O(2^n). Think of the number of possible binary strings of length N, where you can construct a subsequence by the mask of each possible binary string (take a letter if 1, ignore it if 0).

If you want to find all possible substrings, this comes down to the implementation of strings in the language you're using. In c++, it's fairly trivial to do an n^2, but in java it would be O(n^3) since substring / concatenation is O(n) (Although you could do it in n^2 in java, just have to be tricky about what you do :)). Not sure what it is in, im guessing this is python (you should tag your question with the language you're using if you include code), but you could look it up. You could also time it with differently sized inputs, it wouldn't be hard to get a measurable runtime with a complexity of n^2.

Comment: yes, thank you i was having trouble finding the right code because that the right term is subsequences.

Comment: if I answered your question, accept the answer as correct. And/or upvote the answer.